# UIAlertView not firing, after UIActionSheet is displayed

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I have been searching high and low for the answer to my issue. You see I have a UIActionSheet and I am firing it off when the user tries to press a button that they aren't supposed to: it works great, but I am trying to fire of a UIAlert letting the user know the current operation has been stopped and they need to press "Continue" ... my problem is in my - (void) actionSheet .... either the method is not called by the actionSheet or the buttonIndex is not set correctly.

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DVRRemote : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) BOOL pwrOff;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL dvrState;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL playState;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL rcdState;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL rcdPlay;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *pwrSwitch;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dvrStateLbl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PwrLbl;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)pwrPressed:(UISwitch *)sender;
@end
```

and here is the code `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertView` ... please help. This work is already two weeks overdue.

### .m

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (_pwrOff == NO)
    {
        if (_rcdPlay == NO)
        {
            if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual: @"Play"])
            {
                _dvrStateLbl.text = @"Playing";
                _playState = YES;
                _rcdState = NO;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Play not Allowed during Record" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [actionSheet showInView: self.view];
        }
    }
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Playing" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recording stopped"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

please note: I have coded the alert under every `buttonIndex == 0, == 1, == 2` ... it does not want to show.

Big thanks to someone who can help! 
Regards,

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your delegate to your view controller (the object that you want to receive your action sheet delegate methods) via:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Play not Allowed during Record" 
    delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you both so much... I can't wait unitl I can start contributing to this great site!!

Answer (score 1):

Your actionSheet delegate is nil, you didn't set your delegate.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Play not Allowed during Record" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet showInView: self.view];
```

Comment: +1 to you... you thought (and realized) the same thing at the same time I did.

Comment: Thanks. I Didn't realise there's already a correct answer. Wouldn't even try to if I realised earlier.

Comment: Thank you... I was getting error when I put in delegate:self, so when I put in delegate:nil ... the error went away, I guess I didn'take a closer look my cancelButtonTitle: was CancelButtonTitle.